# A Power Series Solution to a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Find a power series solution to the following equation:
>   $$z''=\frac{4}{t}z'+z=0$$
>
> which is bounded by $t=0$ with $z(0)=1$, $z'(0)=0$.

So far this is what I have:

$z=\sum_{n=0}{c_nt^n}$

$z'=\sum_{n=1}{c_nnt^{n-1}}$

$z''=\sum_{n=2}{c_nn(n-1)t^{n-2}}$

Plugging these into the initial equation and grouping sums I get

$0=\sum_{n=0}{c_nt^n+4c_{n+1}(n+1)\frac{t^n}{t}+c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)t^n}$

Factoring out $t_n$ I get an equation involving $c_n$:

$c_n+4c_{n+1}(\frac{n+1}{t})+c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)=0$

So do I just solve this and I am done? I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, do not change the indices and do not forget to devide by $t$ the expansion of the first derivative.

So, $$z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n\quad ,\quad z'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n c_n t^{n-1}\quad,\quad z''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) c_n t^{n-2}$$ which make the differential equation$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) c_n t^{n-2}=4\sum_{n=0}^\infty n c_n t^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n$$ Now, consider a given term $t^m$; you then have  $$(m+2)(m+1)c_{m+2}=4(m+2)c_{m+2}+c_m$$ that is to say  $$(m+2)(m-3)c_{m+2}=c_m$$ that is to say, if $m\neq 3$, $$c_{m+2}=\frac{c_m}{(m+2)(m-3)}$$ the initial conditions giving $c_0=1$ and $c_1=0$. For sure, you need to use the fact that $c_3=0$. All the other terms are perfectly defined.